# Hide Button on search box focus

Tags: html, css, less

I am trying to hide buttons upon focusing on the search box and show it when focus out.

```
<div class="top-bar">
    <div class="search-container">
        <button >MyButton</button>
         <button >MyButton2</button>
         <button >MyButton3</button>

        <input class="search" type="search" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.top-bar {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.search-container {
    max-width: 950px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.search {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 75px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    float: right;
}
.search:focus {
    width: 200px;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fUDBC/39/)

But it is not working fine.Any Ideas???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no previous selector in CSS. If you want the desired effect your buttons will need to come after your search field in your HTML markup.

You can then use a [general sibling selector (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).

```css
.top-bar {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.search-container {
    max-width: 950px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.search {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 75px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    float: right;
}
.search:focus {
    width: 200px;
}
.search:focus ~ button {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-bar">
    <div class="search-container">
        <input class="search" type="search" placeholder="Search">
        <button >MyButton</button>
        <button >MyButton2</button>
        <button >MyButton3</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet.. Can we hide a particular div like this.For eg: a div that is placed outside the search-container ?

Comment: No, CSS doesn't have a parent selector so I'm afraid not. You would need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to modify your HTML structure just a little bit by moving the `input` field before your `button'`s and then add this to your CSS:

```
.search:focus ~ button {
     display: none;
}
```

In the above CSS, I've used the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors), i.e. `~`, which `separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common parent.`

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fUDBC/45/)**.

```css
.top-bar {
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.search-container {
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.search {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 75px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  float: right;
}
.search:focus {
  width: 200px;
}
.search:focus ~ button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="search-container">
    <input class="search" type="search" placeholder="Search">
    <button>MyButton</button>
    <button>MyButton2</button>
    <button>MyButton3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, put input tag above the buttons.

And add the following to the CSS:

```
.search:focus ~ button {
    display:none;
}
```